# Is it possible to cancel a key combination half way through?

Tags: key-bindings

Being new to Emacs, it often happens to me that I press some key combination and then, seeing the preview with `which-key` of how the key combination should finish, realize that I made a mistake somewhere, and I want to use none of the combinations shown.

Is there a way to then cancel a partially completed key combination? I usually end up pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>, in the hope that there is no combination that ends in <kbd>ESC</kbd> (which sometimes is not true). Is there a better way?

Comment: I use `abort-recursive-edit` intuitively in that situation. As I use Caps Lock for this command I can be sure, that no other command will be invoked when I use my personal binding.

Answer (score 9):

In short, type <kbd>C-g</kbd>

Read the manual page on Quitting:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs) Quitting`